# Sphinx meth role does not create a link

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, cross-reference

In a python module, in the docstring of the module I have the following:

```
:meth:`my_method`
```

and I have the following class in the current module:

```
class GameP:

    ...

    def my_method(self):
        return f"{self._name} {self.selected}"
```

Sphinx does not create a link for that, whilst in the Sphinx documentation we have:

> Normally, names in these roles are searched first without any further qualification, then with the current module name prepended, then with the **current module and class name** (if any) prepended. If you prefix the name with a dot, this order is reversed. For example, in the documentation of Python’s codecs127 module, :py:func:`open` always refers to the built-in function, while :py:func:`.open` refers to codecs.open().

Why does the bolded section not hold for me? `:meth:` role does not make a link for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is not crystal clear IMHO, but it works if you use `` :meth:`.my_method` ``  (with a dot). The dot makes Sphinx look for a match for `my_method` anywhere.

The dot is not needed if the cross-reference is in the docstring of the `GameP` class. But in this case the cross-reference is in the module docstring, and on the module level there is no "current class name".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've read the document, and it says that the `.` is used to reverse the searching operation. This differs from what you have referred to. You've said *Anywhere*. Can you tell me what we have in sphinx docs is wrong?

Comment: I think *If you prefix the name with a dot, this order is reversed* is unclear. But it also says *if the name is prefixed with a dot, and no exact match is found, the target is taken as a suffix and all object names with that suffix are searched.* That is what I mean when I say that Sphinx will look for a match anywhere.